# FTDI chip returns descriptor of unknown device

Tags: usb, serial, ftdi

I would like to debug the kernel of my nexus 5 and I sent to a fab the design for the [debu cable](https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/debugcable/+/master) that uses internally a `FTDI` chip that creates a `USB` to serial bridge.

Since the chip is a `QFN` package is a little bit annoying to solder but after some tries I done it; one of the board is seen correctly, indeed from the `syslog`

```
kernel: [12174.440550] usb 3-14: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
kernel: [12174.585763] usb 3-14: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=6001
kernel: [12174.585766] usb 3-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: [12174.585767] usb 3-14: Product: DCSD USB UART
kernel: [12174.585768] usb 3-14: Manufacturer: FTDI
kernel: [12174.585768] usb 3-14: SerialNumber: A600ASO8
mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-14"
mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 5 was not an MTP device
kernel: [12174.606497] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial
kernel: [12174.606569] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
kernel: [12174.606633] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
kernel: [12174.608070] usbcore: registered new interface driver ftdi_sio
kernel: [12174.608128] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for FTDI USB Serial Device
kernel: [12174.608173] ftdi_sio 3-14:1.0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter detected
kernel: [12174.608245] usb 3-14: Detected FT232RL
kernel: [12174.608427] usb 3-14: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

Other two boards instead are seen as a **DCSD Status LED**

```
kernel: [11309.878562] usb 3-14: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
kernel: [11310.024048] usb 3-14: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=8a88
kernel: [11310.024051] usb 3-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
kernel: [11310.024052] usb 3-14: Product: DCSD Status LED
kernel: [11310.024053] usb 3-14: Manufacturer: FTDI
kernel: [11310.024054] usb 3-14: SerialNumber: A101FPA7
```

I googled it but I haven't found anything related to it.

Since two devices return the same exact descriptor I don't think it's an error of transmission but something else, anyone has idea of what can cause this behaviour?

P.S: The chip has been bought from aliexpress so I can't say are original.

**EDIT**

As indicated by the solution, the chip was reprogrammed.

BTW thanks to the comment of @pjc50 I looked for a way of rewriting the EEPROM: on a Debian system you can install `ftdi-eeprom` and after that you have to write a configuration file with the desired `VID` and `PID`

```
vendor_id=0x0403        # Vendor ID
product_id=0x6001       # Product ID
```

and then use the program to reflash the chip

```
$ sudo ftdi_eeprom --device i:0x0403:0x8a88 --flash-eeprom ftdi.conf
```

(`ftdi.conf` is the name of the configuration file described above).

Now I have the device correctly indentified by the kernel.

Comment: They have different "product ID" which is being interpreted differently. Can you reprogram this ID?

Comment: Uh, no? The working one sends *idProduct=6001*, while the others send *idProduct=8a88*. Further, the product string *DCSD Status LED* is sent by the device, and the kernel prints it in verbatim.

Comment: maybe, from the datasheet http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf page 34 and 35 talks about internal EEPROM configuration that can be reprogrammed with an application via ``USB``. BTW I'm more interested about the reason of this different PID :)

Comment: @gipi: Two obvious reasons: the chip was programmed wrong, or it is fake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the FTDI chip is preprogrammed with a custom PID.

You can reprogram it with [FT_PROG](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm#FT_PROG).